# Hay alguna forma o función que IReport Designer me permita imprimir la fecha de mi servidor

Tags: ireport

Hay alguna forma o función que IReport Designer me permita imprimir la fecha de mi servidor sin ninguna clase Java cuando imprima el documento.

Comment: Tengo solo creado mi BD y los datos se muestran, pero hay alguna función que me imprima la fecha del servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si todavía usas el viejo iReport debes saber que es obsoleto y que desde diciembre de 2015 dejó de ser actualizado.

Está bien claro en la [página de `iReport`](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que dice la nota es esto:

> A partir de la versión 5.5.0, Jaspersoft Studio será el cliente de
>   diseño oficial de JasperReports. iReport seguirá siendo un producto
>   compatible en modo de solo mantenimiento hasta el 31 de diciembre de
>   2015, lo que significa que continuaremos solucionando los defectos
>   críticos en las próximas versiones, pero no se agregarán nuevas
>   funciones al cliente iReport. ¡Continúe manteniendo sus informes
>   existentes con el nuevo Jaspersoft Studio!

De hecho, ahora existe una herramienta de diseño bastante mejorada con respecto al antiguo diseñador de iReport, se llama **[Jaspersoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio)**.

Mostraré varias formas de poner la fecha actual en un reporte cualquiera.

En la paleta tienes un pequeño widget que te sirve para poner la fecha / hora actual. Ahí lo tienes, dice **`Current Date`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo lo seleccionas con el ratón y lo arrastras a la parte del reporte que quieras:

Ahí lo he arrastrado al pie de la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vamos a ver un preview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos darle otro formato si queremos. Volvamos a la pestaña `Design`.
Seleccionamos el campo, clic derecho  y luego `Show Properties`, luego `Text field` y en el input `Pattern` escribes esto: **`dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy`** o cualquier otro formato válido deseado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veamos el Preview:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Otras posibilidades

- Puedes usar directamente código de Java en un campo de texto. Es tan fácil como arrastrar un `TextField`, hacer doble clic sobre él y escribir por ejemplo esto en el editor de expresiones que se abrirá:

  ```
  new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy").format(new Date())
  ```
- Desde la versión 5.1.2 puedes usar expresiones como `TODAY()`. Si abres un campo de texto y escribes simplemente: `TODAY()`, te mostrará la fecha actual, y le puedes dar formato como hicimos antes. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes ver el artículo titulado *[Custom Functions in Report Expressions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/index.html#functions)*.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su respuesta, y dar diferentes opciones para aprender mejor, estoy comenzando y es de gran ayuda.