# Cambiar consulta de sql en un jasperReport desde java

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports

Buen dia, mi pregunta es si existe un modo para modificar una consulta de un jasperRepot desde java y como se haría, he buscado pero aun no me queda claro si esto es o no posible.

```
String Reporte=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/reportes/"+archivo;
        //JasperReport masterReport=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(Reporte);

        //Reporte=(JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(Reporte);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Reporte, null,conexion);

        JasperViewer jView=new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);

        jView.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. De cualquier modo, desde Java puedes preparar la consulta y mandarla a Jasper o puedes crear una consulta en Jasper con parámetros, los cuales son dinámicos y pasarlos desde Java. O sea, lo que preguntas se puede interpretar de múltiples maneras. En cualquier caso, se necesita ver tu código (indicándonos dónde falla y cuál es el fallo) y conocer tu contexto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy haciendo una aplicacion de escritorio, la cual requiere de tener informes, en los cuales debo de colocar una fecha que introduzca el usuario para asi generar el reporte del dia, entonces quiero modificar la consulta para que tome un dato agregado por el usuario(la fecha) y de este modo genere el reporte

Comment: Al parecer lo que necesitas es una consulta dinámica. [Aquí te dejo un enlace](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html) que puedes usar como punto de partida. Lo que quieres hacer es posible, haciendo lo explicado en esa guía. OJO, usa la última versión de Jasper, la cual tiene muchísimas mejoras y facilidades sobre el tema de las consultas. He visto que muchos programadores siguen usando una versión obsoleta ([ver esta respuesta al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209148/29967)).