# Error Conexion Plugin Ireport y Mysql

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Buen dia.
Estoy teniendo problemas con la conexion desde el Plugin Ireports hacia MYSQL.
las versiones son las siguientes.
Netbeans 8.0.2
Plugin Ireports 5.5.0
Mysql 8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los .jar correspondientes a mi version

**Error : SQL problems: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**

Comment: No entiendo muy bien por qué usas un plugin para conectar a la base de datos ¿? Por otra parte, iReport fue declarado obsoleto desde hace cuatro años (en 2015, [ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209148/29967)), por lo que me temo que estás programando código problemático para el presente y el futuro sobre todo. Tampoco entiendo qué tiene que ver esto con Javascript ¿?

Comment: Entiendo, que esta obsoleto, ahora la alternativa de ireports es JasReports Estudio, pero aquí viene mi consulta se puede trabajar con netbeans? Eh leído que solo es compatible con eclipse,por favor sácame de dudas, saludos cordiales

Comment: MySQL 8 salió años después que iReport 5.6 y NetBeans 8.0.2 ¿actualizaste mysql-connector?

Comment: claro tengo el mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar con este jar mis conexiones son estables.