# ¿Como generar reportes de iReport con API restful en Java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

estoy realizando una app en Java para escritorio, y tengo que generar reportes con iReport con el plugin para NetBeans, como saben, para generar el reporte se le pasa el archivo.jasper, los parámetros y la conexión,

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parameters, conexion);
JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
```

Pero la aplicación trabaja con una API rest, es decir, no hay una conexión directa a la BD dentro del código, todo es mediante la API. procesando la información en formato JSON, entonces, ¿hay alguna manera de generar los reportes de iReport mediante una conexión de API rest, y que este procese la información en formato JSON?

Comment: Primeramente, `iReport` fue declarado obsoleto en 2015 y ya no es actualizado ni mantenido. Se recomienda migrar a Jasper Studio ([ver más detalles aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209148/29967)). En cuanto al JSON, puedes usarlo como fuente de datos (Datasource) de tu reporte, y funcionará como si fuese la base de datos, sólo que en vez de tomar los datos de la BD, los tomará del JSON remoto que te ofrece la API. [Aquí hay un tutorial que explica cómo hacerlo](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-report-uses-remote-json-data-source).

Comment: Gracias, lo he revisado, pero tienes que poner el link directamente, además de que el reporte lo genera en el navegador y el reporte se que tiene generar directo en la app de escritorio, y se tiene que usar JWT