# Reporte con Ireport y java

Tags: ireport

estoy realizando mi primer reporte utilizando la herramienta Ireport, corresponde a una factura, la cual diseñé correctamente pero cuando ejecuto mi programa me muestra titulos y pie de pagina pero el detalle no aparece...al hacer Preview tampoco aparece el detalle....
Acá dejo el diseño y el Preview

[image: Diseño]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No sabemos cómo estás definiendo el reporte (el jrxml) ni cómo lo estás alimentando (desde una clase Java? en un servidor jasperreports y un datasource?) para saber por qué está tomando las variables como literales. No sabemos qué quieres decir con _cuando ejecuto mi programa_. Explícanos. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Lo estoy alimentando en un programa java con datasource...pero me da la impresion que el problema está en el ireport porque cuando hago una vista previa ya no aparece el detalle...

Comment: Si no revisas los enlaces en los comentarios y editas la pregunta como se te indica, te van a cerrar la pregunta. Tómate el tiempo de mejorar la pregunta y vas a recibir buenas respuestas

Comment: iReport fue declarado obsoleto en 2015 si mal no recuerdo. Considera usar JasperReport en su lugar. [Ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209148/29967).